# BigQuery scheduled queries are created with the wrong Region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have never had issues with this until today.
My dataset is in Europe. Every time I create a new scheduled query I select the "Automatic location selection" and everything goes right.
Today every query I create is set in the US, so of course it doesn't work.
I try to Edit it and change it to automatic, or even Multiregion -> Europe. The check turns green since now it's supposed to find the dataset so I save it, but once I go back to the query it is still in the US, so the change is not being saved.
My coworker tried with her user and exactly the same happens.

¿Any idea of what is happening and how to solve it?

I tried creating a new scheduled query with both multiregion: europe and automatic location, always saves as US. I also tried editing it as stated before but it still saves as US.